# Domino web service Single sign on is required?

Tags: web-services, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We have intranet based notes applications. We need to create a web service provider from notes and it needs to be consumed from other internet based application.

Note- the consumer will be triggered from external environment not from our network.

For Eg: Network X is ours, all the note application works only in network X(not in internet). It means that single sign on is not enabled. The external application is in network Y.

We have a provider and it works fine in our end. But we need to consume it from the external application, it is ASP .Net.

Question :

1. Does Single Sign on need to be enabled in our domino server?
2. Is there any possible to consume my provider without enabling single sign on from external application?
3. Which is the secured web service scenario in Lotus notes domino?

We are using notes 8.5.3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "We are using notes 8.5.3." - I feel for you.

Comment: Why? any specific reason?

Answer (score 0):

I will start a response, but I'm afraid that you didn't gave enough information to get the response you need.

Basically, your WS provider is anonymous, so a consumer calling it from the Y network will act as anonymous.

[edited]

From your network Y, simply open the WSDL to check that you have access:

```
//server/yourdb.nsf/WS_name?wsdl
```

Using tool like SoapUI, try to consume it.

According to you remark (hello word) you don't need what I mention below about security. I suggest you to read [Creating your first Web Service provider and consumer in LotusScript and Java.](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_your_first_Web_Service_provider_and_consumer_in_LotusScript_and_Java.)

*Security*

If the data you want to send are publicly accessible, you have not to care about security and SSO. If in contrast you need to give access thru your WS to a limited audience, you will have to read and do what IBM recommends:

[How to secure a web service hosted on a Domino server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295968)

I suggest you to provide some information:

- in which language is the WS (LS / Java)
- how/what ganularity did you implement the security (reader field, or ACL)
- What is the data you
  are returning with your WS

Comment: My WS is in LS, I am just returning a string based on the current database's document. User can login from network X(intranet- within our organization), not able to login from internet(From my home network). Also ACL does not perform any role here. Do I need to set any setting in webservice for accessing the provider from internet.

Comment: what do you mean by "current database's document" ? current to what ? basically (I mean in a standard call) your WS is anonymous: no user. If the  information you have to return is public as you do not need to login or SSO.

Comment: My requirement is very simple, I just want return a simple hello world string... In my application, anonymous access is having reader access. I can open the WSDL in my office network and I can consume and it is working fine. But I can not consume it from my home network. All what I need is, from external application how to consume webservice, if domino is constructed like mentioned. Do I need to disable/ enable the server setting for accessing the webservice from external network.